# why doesn't the_content() work in this {single-custom_post_type.php} page?

Tags: custom-post-types, the-content, template-tags

This code is from my page `single-publication.php`.

It outputs the relevant custom fields etc (here wrapped in template tags), but `the_content()` won't output the post content. I've resorted to using `$post->post_content` (which works), but the mystery remains:

```
<div class="publication-info">
    <?php printf("<h2>%s</h2>", get_the_title() ); ?>
    <div class="publication-meta publication-credit"><?php the_publication_credit(); ?></div>
    <div class="publication-meta publication-date"><?php the_publication_date(); ?></div><br />
    <div class="publication-blurb" style="font-family:sans-serif;"><?php echo $post->post_content; // the_content() doesn't work. Why not? ?></div>
</div>
```

What's going on here?

**EDIT:** I was driven to ask this question because I believed - mistakenly, as it turns out - that `$post` working and `get_the_title()` returning a title were an ironclad sign of being inside the loop. But apparently this is not the case. cf [Codex on The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) (second para) and [Codex on get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) (parameter list). Can anyone explain?

Comment: Is your publication-info block inside the loop?

Comment: I'm assuming so, as `$post` is populated and `get_the_title()` works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Some post-related data is not available to get_posts by default**, such as post content through `the_content()`, or the numeric ID. This is resolved by calling an internal function **`setup_postdata()`**, with the **$post** array as its argument:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

See [**Access all post data**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Access_all_post_data)

Answer (score 9):

There's a good chance your HTML is not included in the loop. Make sure your code looks like this:

```
if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <div class="publication-info">
        <?php printf("<h2>%s</h2>", get_the_title() ); ?>
        <div class="publication-meta publication-credit"><?php the_publication_credit(); ?></div>
        <div class="publication-meta publication-date"><?php the_publication_date(); ?></div><br />
        <div class="publication-blurb" style="font-family:sans-serif;"><?php echo $post->post_content; // the_content() doesn't work. Why not? ?></div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: yes, this works. thanks. but how could I possibly get_the_title() from outside the loop? the codex says `$ID
(int) (optional) Post ID or leave empty to use current post in The Loop`

Comment: Because it uses the $post object that is set for the page. It's a bit wonky for sure.  the_content() is dependent on the_post() function.

Comment: Yes, you have to place `the_content()` function inside the loop. The way i feel `the_content()` should be set in a `single.php` or `post-type.php` file. But for some reason its not. You still need to have a loop in the `single.php` or `post-type.php` file.

Comment: thanks a lot. a final request: can you point me to any resource that explains a bit more about when and how $post is actually set, if it's not set at the start of the loop? would like to understand.

Comment: @BrianFegter correct me if I'm wrong: in `single-{post_type}.php`, there is always 1 post. Therefore, the `while(have_posts()){}` can be omitted. Isn't it?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Best practices to always include the loop

Comment: I'm confused by this too. Can anyone explain more clearly why the title is available outside the loop, but the content isn't? @Brian you say that it is because it uses the post object set for the page, but doesn't that also contain the content data? What am I missing here please?